# Python 3.6+ How do I create a json dump file instantly inside a while loop. Its only added after the while loop terminates

Tags: json, python-3.x, while-loop, dump

I have a while loop that calls different methods based on user input. One method is a save to json file. I would like the file to appear straight away so that I can continue using the while loop for other commands. I have seen some answers to similar questions about using .flush(), close() or buffering=0. However they did not seem to work.

```
def running_prog(self):
    while self.running:
        self.next_command = input("Which command do you wish to use, enter number or write \'quit\':\n "
                             "1: Create Tree, 2: Load Tree, 3: Save Tree \n"
                             "4: Delete Tree, 5: Add Branch, 6: Remove Branch \n"
                             "7: Complete Task, quit: quit\n")
        if self.next_command.lower() == 'quit':
            self.running = False
        else:
            self.call_methods(int(self.next_command))
```

This is the while loop

```
def save_json_tree(self):
    self.make_folder('Trees')
    self.make_folder('Trees/{}'.format(self.tree.name))
    json_tree = self.convert_tree_to_json()
    file_name = self.create_file_name()
    with open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf8') as json_file:
        json.dump(json_tree, json_file)
```

This is the save method.
As mentioned I have tried playing with json_file.close(), json_file.flush() and buffering=0. None of these seem to make it work.

Comment: You are using the file in with context. That should close the file automatically. IMO this should work. How are you determining it is not working?  Is the filename same in next loop also?

Comment: Bookmarked to see how to resolve this.

Comment: The file would not appear in the IDE, I looked at the folder via windows explorer and it appeared! So thanks... I spent like 2 hours on that :)